# Groovy Jenkins powershell pipe not working

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I want to replace some text in a file after Jenkins does its build step.

I have the code below in my post build step.

```
powershell.exe -Command(Get-Content "./PublishedWebsites/app.config") |
Foreach-Object {$_.replace({{MyDummValue}}, "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")} | 
Set-Content "./PublishedWebsites/app.config"
```

The first part works `(Get-Content "./PublishedWebsites/app.config")` up until the pipe ("|").

After the pipe it throws an error  that **Foreach-Object is not recognized by an internal or external command.**

I am thinking it has something to do with the escape sequence and the syntax.
So I have tried this as well

```
"""powershell.exe -Command(Get-Content "./PublishedWebsites/app.config") |
    Foreach-Object {$_.replace({{MyDummValue}}, "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")} | 
    Set-Content "./PublishedWebsites/app.config"""
```

Then for some reason jenkins is trying to evaluate the `$_.replace({{MyDummValue}}` before the post build step is even reached and gives me the error of **'Cannot get property replace on null object'**

So I am at a loss. All I want to do is on a post build step, rename a value in a file with the Build Number.

Answer (score 0):

When calling PowerShell (or other) scripts from Groovy, always use **single-quoted** (or triple-single-quoted) string literals for the script. With double-quoted (or triple-double-quoted) strings, Groovy tries to **interpolate** the string, so you'd have to escape `$` as `\$`, to use it literally. While this is just a nuisance, double-quoted strings are also prone to **script injection**, where a pipeline user might run arbitrary PowerShell scripts, when pipeline parameters are interpolated by Groovy within the script.

Another mistake: the value `{{MyDummValue}}` isn't quoted.

Also, I don't know why you are calling `powershell.exe` explicitly. Use the `powershell` step instead:

```sh
post {
    always {  // or one of the other available sections
        powershell '''
            Get-Content "./PublishedWebsites/app.config" |
                Foreach-Object {$_.replace("{{MyDummValue}}", $env:BUILD_NUMBER)} |
                Set-Content "./PublishedWebsites/app.config"
        '''
    }
}
```